# What Android SDK should I use now?

Tags: android, sdk, version

I'm planning on trying to make a game to put on the Android Play Store soon, and I was wondering what SDK should I use now? I know there's 4.1 out for Jellybean, but should I still go for an older one like 2.2 or 2.3?

Comment: @ the closers : how is "too localized" even remotely applicable for "game developmment for android" ?

Comment: @Peter *"too localized -
This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to [..] a specific moment in time"*. This information here will be outdated in 2 months *(hence "now" in the question)*. Game dev has nothing to do with the close votes. Apart from that: The question is somewhat subjective, so not constructive applies as well. If you got a lot of money and time, maybe it's reasonable to go for a lower sdk. If you don't have that, go higher, etc.

Comment: I get your point,  but a lot of the info won't be outdated : this info I read here already : differenct min version, target verstion, links to versions used, considerations to take into account ect.... all relevant in 2 months and longer

Comment: @Peter But that is not the information that the question asks for. Maybe it should be "What should I take into consideration when picking a min/target version?" instead. I don't know. Won't argue over it any further, a specific version is bound to a point in time.

Comment: @alextsc, guess you're right, greetz, peter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should still at least target API level 10 which currently has about 60% share:
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

You can use the support library (v4) to get new classes like fragments.

Answer (score 8):

There are statistics on what devices are wide spread over the users of the Google Play market to be found here: [Android Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform)

At the time of this writing **(September 2014)**, it looks like this:

[image: Android Usage 13th. of September 2014]

Seeing the statistics, I would go for Jelly Bean (Android 4.1 +).

Answer (score 2):

So use the dashboard like everyone says to go down to 2.1-2.2 but don't forget that should be your **min SDK**. Your **target sdk** number should be *16* (as noted the #io2012). This will make sure that your styles get rendered nicely for the new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Lower versions like 2.1 and 2.3 mean you would get more customers.
Whereas on the other hand ICS and JellyBean would provide you with improved functionalities.

Choose a version such that there is a balance between the functionalities and the potential target audience.

For example, if you went for JB, then there would be many users who wouldn't be having JB yet and thus you would b losing your potential users.

*(I personally prefer 2.3.3)*

Answer (score 1):

This is your choice, yet if you would have a larger audience when using an older SDK, since more devices would be supported. I'd suggest you use 2.2. Here are Google's stats of Android SDK usage[link](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of game you are planning to develop. [This](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/game-development-for-android-quick.html) might give you a hint. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you target 2.2 and earlier, you will probably touch 95% of the market.
If you use Eclipse you should update all your tools and then try to create an Android project, Google show some satistics, but the best place to look at is here : http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4.1, & declare uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:maxSdkVersion="16" in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="16" android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

**minSdkVersion**
This is primarily the code base that you take on most of your API set from.

**targetSdkVersion**
This is the highest possible SDK that you can test with, devices using your app will look and feel more at home when that targetSdk is high enough to allow.

**multi-versioning**
When you want to use a higher level feature than your minSdkVersion. you can block off calls with Build.Version.X eg.

```
    File path;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        path = new           File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + directory);
    } else {
        path = new File(getBestCacheDir(applicationContext, true) + File.separator + "Pictures" + File.separator + directory);
    }
```

Be careful not to accidentally use higher level API features than your minSDK as this will cause a run-time crash.